Prometheus alert if two expressions are true
I'm trying to create an alert in Prometheus that should notify me if two hosts are unavailable.
I have two metrics:
probe_success{instance="host1"}
probe_success{instance="host2"} 

that returns 1 if host availiable and 0 if host unavailable.
How I can combine this two metrics in one expression?
I tried using on() probe_success{instance="host1"} == 0 and on() probe_success{instance="host2"} == 0, it works but it only returns the first expression so the email only has labels from host1. It looks like the problem is with only one host.
Also tried sum(probe_success{ instance=~"host1|host2"}) == 0, but here I have no labels at all.
Is there some posibility to create expression with logic like
if((probe_success{instance="host1"}==0) and (probe_success{instance="host2"}==0)){
       notifyMe("host1","host2")
    }


If you are OK with hardcodding both hosts in query, it'll be way easier to puth the both also into label of alert rule directly.

If you are looking to get something more dinamic, you'll need to join labels (after renaming one of them), but it'll be quite a cumbersome query.

@markalex Yes, I can hardcode them. I was thinking about it like my last option because harcode usually looks bad. It seemed to me that there should be some kind of option that has logic like the AND operator in other languages. If there is only one option with a cumbersome query, I will use hardcode.

In prometheus, you can create a rule that will alert on each host that is unavailable if none of of them is up.
- alert: MissingAllHosts
  expr: (probe_success == 0) UNLESS ON() ( sum(probe_success) != 0 )
  ...

Then use alertmanager's grouping for sending a single notification
routes:
  - match:
      alertname: 'MissingAllHosts'
    group_by: ['alertname']
    group_wait: 1m
    group_interval: 10s

The resulting alert should contain the list of hosts that were expected.
